# Material Icon showing as the name when site first loads

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

There is an issue with Angular 7 and materials icon where the name of the icon shows when the site is initially loading.

Is there a way to prevent this

[image]

Comment: Add to your index.html :   <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

Comment: unfortunately our servers are locked down with no internet access. All css needs to be installed in app.

Comment: so copy everything from https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/materialicons/v50/flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNc.woff2 and put into your file

Answer (score 0):

**Add your stylesheet reference to `<head>`**

If you stylesheet for Material or for the Material Icons is located lower in the index.html file or is lazy loaded, there will be a brief moment where the text for the icon is displayed rather than the icon itself.

In you `index.html` add this between the `<head></head>` tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```